# How can I navigate list-group through keyboard (up/ down)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I navigate (using jQuery) through this list-group with keys up and down?

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li  class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
</ul>
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You can use key event with arrow key press by javascript,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) to your `<ul>`, [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) `keydown` to the `.list-group`.
Use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) and [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to make sure it will work in the `<li>`s size, getting its [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/).
Take the `<li>` you want with [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

*(You will need to focus the div to work with this)*

Sample:

```js
$(function() {
   $('.list-group').focus();
});

const firstIndex = $(this).find('.list-group-item').first().index();
const lastIndex = $(this).find('.list-group-item').last().index();

$('.list-group').bind('keydown', function(e){
  var index = $(this).find('.active').index();
  
  switch(e.which){
    case 38:
      index = (index == firstIndex ? lastIndex : index - 1);
      break;
    case 40:
      index = (index == lastIndex ? 0 : index + 1);
      break;
  }
  
  $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).find('.list-group-item:eq( '+ index +' )').addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
.active{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group" tabindex="0">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
</ul>
```