# How to keyboard navigate ListGroup and ListGroupItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, reactstrap, keyboard-navigation

I'm trying to keyboard navigate ListGroup / ListGroup items in a logical way.
My app is setup with:

- Div(s)
- ListGroup
- ListGroupItem

I have the tabIndex=0 on all items. (I'm using a framework where other components within the hierarchy are set to an index=0, and I cannot change them. Thus, to maintain flow, everything is set to 0).

Keyboard navigation works well, I can tab to each component. However, I'd like to be able to tab into the ListGroup, and move through the items AND have the ability to escape back to the parent component, almost like a skip-nav idea. With a large list, one needs to tab or shift-tab through all the items to get back to other parts of the app.

How can I keyboard navigate the items in a better way?
I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414459/how-can-i-navigate-list-group-through-keyboard-up-down) which shows a way using jQuery to arrow up/down on a `li` item, but I'm looking for a way to do this to a reactstrap list.

[Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/khibma/pen/poEwPex)

ListGroup / ListGroupItem code snippet

```
 <ListGroup className="listgroup" key={this.state.selectedFac} tabIndex={0} >  
          { this.state.allRecords.map((feat,i) =>{
              return (                 
                <ListGroupItem key={feat.objectid} action 
                  onClick={() => this.selectedSite(feat.objectid)}
                  href={`${feat.objectid}`}
                  active={this.state.selectedFac == feat.objectid ? true : false}
                  tabIndex={0}>
                     {feat.objectid}
                </ListGroupItem>               
              )
            })
          }
        </ListGroup>
```

Comment: If it is possible to set a keypress event on items, then you can put a ref on parent and set focus on parent on escape key press.

Comment: Thanks @AchalJain do you have a link to reading or documentation on this?

Comment: These link might help:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440408/how-to-detect-esc-key-press-in-react-and-how-to-handle-it
2. https://medium.com/@seif_ghezala/how-to-create-an-accessible-react-modal-5b87e6a27503

Comment: @AchalJain thanks! will give a read. If I'm able to build out a solution I'll circle back and self-answer.